The "essence" of a typical graduate course in complex analysis
It is probably just me, but for the life of me, I'm unable to boil complex analysis down to a few easily digestible principles that are more specific than "holomorphic functions are super nice". Yes, complex analysis is beautiful because of this, but also, how do I organize it into a few coherent intuitions? I particularly refer to the syllabus of a graduate course, consisting typically of the min/max theorem, harmonic functions, MVT, normal families, conformal maps, residue theorem and argument principle, singularities, Rouche's theorem, etc. (for a book, think Taylor's Introduction to Complex Analysis.)
I thought some of these would be that "meromorphic functions are approximately rational functions of some order near singularities", and "holomorphic functions are locally polynomial + error term", but again, the list seems to be unending and unorganized for me.
From a closer perspective, how do I think of it in terms of certain central proof strategies? I see proofs of theorems and sure they make sense. But then, some question statements are just crazy to me (for ex: how can we have a bound on the supremum of the derivative of all functions, holomorphic on the disk, at a point?). The scope of these problems is intimidating and negates any intuition I felt that I've built about the tools I've learnt about.
By the way, I'm saying this as someone who loves measure theory: it is super visual and the proofs are often very intuitive. Moreover, I always think of it as the central object being a "measure space", so that any fact I learn seems to have grown in a natural direction from what I already know(as opposed to, why do I care about normal families or the harmonic equation, as opposed to anything else, on the complex plane?)
I know that this is probably because I've spent way more time with measure theory than complex analysis, but my above feelings impede me from wanting to study more complex. Therefore, I'd love to hear from anyone with more experience what the "essence" of (graduate) complex analysis is for them - in terms of the content, intuitions and proof strategies.
TLDR: For people who enjoy complex analysis, what is the "essence" of complex analysis (particularly, a typical graduate course in it, syllabus mentioned above) for you? In other words, why should a typical graduate course contain the topics it does - why should a professor talk about min/max theorems, harmonic functions, conformal maps and normal families in a single introductory course? Something like "properties of holomorphic functions" is too broad, whereas the above grouping is, of course, too narrow. I’m interested in this from both the perspective of topics involved and the underlying proof strategies.

I've done topology all the way to cohomology products, but for the life of me I can't get my mind around complex analysis. I've taken basic courses twice, and read multiple books, but still no. I think there might be too many "high value" items, like trying to choose what to order at a restaurant that has your favorite fish dish, type of steak, best pizza, and amazing sushi.

It may be that your experience with measure theory is mostly with general measure spaces and abstract considerations. If one includes the many classical topics that measure theory developed from (e.g. spend some time looking through the material, especially the problems, in Real Analysis by Bruckner/Bruckner/Thomson), I suspect you'd have similar issues in summarizing measure and integration theory.

To me, complex analysis is based on the Cauchy Integral Formula (which you did not even list). The magic that boundary values uniquely determine a function is beautiful and deep — this amounts of the ellipticity of the $\bar\partial$ operator. Of course, the links of complex analysis with topology, differential geometry, and algebraic curves make the subject quite beautiful. To me, measure theory is not geometric at all,  but quite formal.

Agreed with @TedShifrin. I just taught an (undergrad version of) complex analysis for the first time, and in discussions with colleagues before, the upshot was: "There's this family of interconnected theorems that all show holomorphic functions are ridiculously well-behaved, but where do we start, what is the original gateway?" And now I say: It's the Cauchy Integral Formula (and its "derivative versions"). That is the one that conceptually ties everything together. Boundary values determine interior values, woah. Best treatment of how e.g. power series come from that in Ahlfors!

This is not at all an answer to your question, just commiseration that was slightly too long for a comment: I feel the same way as you do about complex analysis! The theorems are just too magical for me, you seem to get out way more than you put in and I've never acquired a clear understanding of why. This is why I also dislike all the complex analysis proofs of the fundamental theorem of algebra; in the topological and algebraic proofs it's at least clearer to me what's happening and why but the complex analysis proofs still feel like magic (in a bad way, as in I don't understand what's happening or why).
If I were to take another stab at complex analysis I'd probably try rereading Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis which is a lovely book; beautifully typeset, nice diagrams, clean proofs, lots of exercises, and applications to other fields. I might also try Needham's Visual Complex Analysis which looks very pretty and seems promising for building intuition.
The only idea in complex analysis I feel like I have any kind of handle on is analytic continuation and, related, the identity theorem. These tell us that meromorphic functions have this kind of incredible robustness to them; they can be reconstructed from arbitrarily small portions of themselves. The reason I feel like I have a handle on this is that it's a generalization of a fact about rational functions, and I feel like I understand those, at least!

I'd like to think that the analytic continuation property should be an instance of more general properties of Dirichlet problems for PDEs. After all, holomorphic functions are those that satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.
